# How do you create a REST API in PHP?

Tags: php, api

I've been developing  gaming site and planning to add an API to let developers create games for the site. The only problem is how do you create an API more specifically a REST API in PHP or any other language that could develop APIs?

Sorry, just new in API Development.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty easy when you understand the fundamentals. Basically you want controllers mapped to actions that modify data, whether that data's in a database, XML file, CSV file, text file depends on your models.

I created a simple API framework starter that you can take a look at and get started with: https://github.com/martinbean/api-framework

Comment: Thanks Martin, your simple API framework is good and I could understand it better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinBean I realise this comes a little later, but is your framework linked above simply a 'starter' for basing your own API on or does it independently handle everything like I've seen many other frameworks do?

Comment: @KristianMatthews It's literally a starter; you build your API on it how you wish. It doesn't assume anything about what your database setup or whatever is. You create your controllers and models; it handles the requests and responses, and is lightweight enough to be extended and built upon.

Comment: @MartinBean That's perfect, exactly what I've been looking for, thank you.

Comment: @KristianMatthews No problem. Drop me an email if I can help further or if you have any other questions.

Comment: As always with SO, a jewel found on a closed "bad" question.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Martin. good job. saved me several hours

Comment: Any idea how I would change the NewsController to access a database?  Or can you update the NewsController to access a MySQL db?  New to REST api and PHP.

Comment: @JPM The framework is designed to not restrict you. You would use it within your own application, where you would have your own model classes that interact with your database.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Recess PHP Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/) . You can do a quick search on Google, there are a lot of articles available :)

Answer (score -1):

I recently used FRAPI to do this,  http://getfrapi.com/

It's focus is on burying all the donkey work and letting you concentrate on what the API really needs to DO!  ... and as an added plus, it generates an API specification with no extra effort required.

**Update 2021/06/01:**  Project no longer exists!