# How can I get the client IP address in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create a web page so that when a user opens it I want to get the client's IP address. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Voting to close. Did you even look for the answer first? I’m sure a Google search would have yielded a result or two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: [Was it so hard to use Google for that?](http://bit.ly/18RHxxl)

Comment: was it is hard if you answer me ?

Comment: You want me to do the work for you? Hire me.

Comment: why you answer me ? you can not answer nobady ask to you

Comment: @user3049398 You would do well to [take the Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn what kind of questions this site is for, rather than then insulting those who are steering you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super-global:

```
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

From the docs:

> **REMOTE_ADDR** 
>  The IP address from which the user is viewing the
>   current page.

Comment: Rep whoring. The OP could have easily found the answer with a Google search. It wasn’t an issue with OP’s PHP code, just laziness.

Comment: thanks , but didn't work !
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $userIp;

Comment: Still a valid answer. No reason to DV...

Comment: @user3049398 This is definitely how it's done. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinBean If you feel that someone is supposed to get a downvote for laziness then it should be the OP in this case not people taking effort to provide an answer to the topic at hand.

Comment: @MartinBean maybe we should downvote your answer here for the same reason? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618734/how-do-you-create-a-rest-api-in-php/10618829#10618829

Comment: @BenM That’s your prerogative. But bear in mind it’s over a year old, has 13 up-votes and has been called a “jewel” in comments, it’d be obvious you were only doing it because of sour grapes and not its content.

Answer (score 2):

You can get IP address using [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super global variable

```
 <?php
    echo  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Comment: already being answered....

Comment: Hey after post my answer I see

Comment: @SureshKamrushi more than one person can answer the same question.

Comment: yes. i did not given downvote, just commented only.

Comment: downvote was probs people who are voting to close, as this is quite an easy thing to search.

Comment: @James Yup. I was one who down-voted. It’s not a programming issue, just laziness on OP’s behalf.

Comment: @MartinBean then punish the OP, not the people answering.

Comment: @BenM I did. Then “punished” you for choosing to answer an easy question instead of voting to close it, as: “Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.**”

Comment: @MartinBean oh wow. You mean like you did here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618734/how-do-you-create-a-rest-api-in-php/10618829#10618829?

Comment: @BenM Yes. Because that could have easily been solved with just one line in PHP after a Google search *rolls eyes*

Comment: My point is that you didn't provide him with any code. Only a link to a website that you likely found through Google. I fail to see how that's different... *rolls eyes*

Comment: @MartinBean BenM does have a point you know. That other question is actually closed as not constructive... (I know that doesn't argue against your point, but fair is fair surely..?)

Comment: @James I agree. But bear in mind that answer was submitted *over one year ago*. I may have posted links to resources and voted to close it myself in the present day. We live, learn, and grow.

Comment: Agreed, things change in a year, and resources for the same questions build up over time too so search rather than ask etc. (FTR I never said what you did was wrong, just that BenM's point was valid ;) )

Comment: @James I know and I agree: in hindsight as I say I would have probably opted to close that question myself. But that’s not the topic on hand and just an attempt to dig up the past to discredit my current actions. If I didn’t know any better, I’d say BenM was in politics with that approach ;)

Comment: @MartinBean If you believe it so strongly, delete your 13 upvote accepted answer... *whistle* (just joking)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following super global:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

However note that people can easily spoof their IP, be on a shared IP, they're using a proxy (so not really their IP) etc.
So sometimes you can get results you may not expect/might not be accurate.